# Need to create a html file in web root folder at startup

Tags: spring

I'm using **spring 3.1**. And I need to **make a html** file in my web root **at spring startUp**.

Of course I know JSP makes a html, but it's about request-response. I need to create a html on the startup.

And.. I hope my job is possible in pure Spring framework.

I know of Quartz.. but I don't want to use quartz. Because I'm afraid that adopting Quartz may need many changes in my Spring config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bean that implements `ApplicationListener`.  An `ApplicationListener` listens to events published by the context.

> The ApplicationContext publishes certain types of events when loading
>   the beans. For example, a ContextStartedEvent is published when the
>   context is started and ContextStoppedEvent is published when the
>   context is stopped.

Using an application listener allows you to execute some tasks when the application is first started or the context is refreshed.

Here is an example of a basic `ApplicationListener` from one of my projects:

```
   public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

        @Override
        public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
             //Generate html file here, this method is called when event happens
        }
    }
```

And its configuration:

```
<!-- Fired when different application events occur such as context refresh or startup -->
<bean id="myListener" class="fully.qualified.MyApplicationListener" />
```