# Create complex HTML file in JAVA

Tags: spring, file-io, createfile

I'm using spring 3.1 and I need to **create HTML file**.

But it's not for the usuall 'request-response' job.

[I have to do this **at Spring startup**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831962/need-to-create-a-html-file-in-web-root-folder-at-startup/16832194?noredirect=1#16832194).

Which means it's should done in JAVA, right? Because it' **not triggered by http request**.

And the HTML is not simple. It has a **complex DOM structure** to display data retrieved from DB.

It would be very tough to create html code in java(hundreads of `out.println();`).

Is there any easy and neat way to create complex HTML in java?

For example.. (it's my imagination)

1. In java(my ApplicationLisener), retrieve a data and store them somewhere.
2. In jsp, create html with the data and send the html code back to java.
3. In java, create html file and place it somewhere.

I hope similar things are possible.

Comment: Apache Velocity is a nice general purpose templating alternative to web-only JSPs, it would enable you to generate HTML "programatically".

Comment: @kryger  I know of Velocity. But I have to use many if-elses and loops... So considering the performance, I want to create HTML file on startup. The HTML contains data from DB, but doesn't have to retrieve it every request. Just once, on startup.